# What is the punishment in the Nights Watch for abandoning your mission?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the latest episode, a Nights Watch member just leaves his assignment/task/mission before completing his assigned objective with no excusing reason.

As he is going back I don't think it counts as desertion, but is there any punishment for this **under normal circumstances** at least in the show or book?

> Sam leaves the Citadel without permission or affirmation from the maesters thus violating his mission of becoming a maester for the Nights Watch. He also steals a few books. For the purpose of this question we will ignore what he may have been doing with Gilly

Comment: @Paulie_D I may have missed something but didn't he just grab a bunch of random books and book it? I don't think there was any indication he knew what was in the books

Comment: @Paulie_D I suppose he did mention some names of Maesters who might know so they could have been their books but it's never really elaborated on if they were useful just might be. Besides that getting off topic, this is about under normal circumstances abandoning the mission or duty

Comment: @Paulie_D I think that's just for Oath breaking or treasonous crimes, being a coward/preoccupied with something else might be something else right?

Comment: His mission isn't just to become a maester, it's also specifically targeted at finding intel that will assist in the fight against the Night King. Since that portion is taking on more urgency, and the maesters are dragging their feet on providing any kind of direct assistance and allowing him to focus his efforts, he's collecting materials useful for that and returning to the Watch.  As such, I'm not sure he's really abandoning his assignment. Though, if he is, there is a family job opening that is timed pretty well for him.....

Comment: @PoloHoleSet There''s no family job...he  isn't allowed to inherit as a member of the Night's Watch. Of course the King can do anything.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Please re-read what I wrote .... "***if he is*** (abandoning)...." If he leaves the Night's Watch, how is a Night's Watch restriction on inheriting relevant? Plus that statement was mostly tongue-in-cheek. If I join the military and I have to sport a crew cut, by rule, how does that bind me in my choice of hairstyle after I desert?

Comment: He can't just *leave* the Nights Watch...it's a permanent thing. The only way to leave is to die...otherwise you are a deserter. and subject to a death sentence. When you join the Watch you give up all inheritance rights...so what familiy job can he have when he has no family?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Who is going to stop him, that far south of the Wall? If he goes home, and takes up that mantle, who is going to say otherwise to him?  Technically, legally, Cersei has no claim to the throne.  Technically, legally, Jon Snow was a deserter. But she's the queen, he's the king of the North. From a practical point of view, if there's no one who can or will say no, Sam can go home and claim his inheritance. The only people in an actual position to want to or be able to oppose him are ash.

Comment: Also, you think the King in the North, his best friend (and the person who wanted his assistance as a Maester in the first place and isn't even there any more) can't decree him to be released from that? No one else cares about the Wall. Will someone in the South care enough to say "hell no!" At the Wall they don't care about him all that much, so if he sends word to Jon he wants out, he's out, as well.

Comment: Note re. Gilly: The Night Watch oath is quite specific. It says "take no wife" and "father no children". It doesn't say "have no relationship with women". In other words, it doesn't say anything about cohabiting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we assume that Samwell is *deserting his post* then there is only one punishment...

### *Death!*

> Desertion is a serious crime in the Seven Kingdoms. It takes place **when a man abandons his post, particularly in times of war**. Deserters are considered outlaws and thus are marked for death.
>
> Within the ranks of the Night's Watch, desertion is considered a form of oathbreaking. Deserters are not only hunted down by sworn brothers of the Watch but also by lords should a deserter enter his lands.
>
> <sup>[Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Desertion)</sup>

However, that doesn't mean the punishment *has* to be imposed.

> Jon Snow briefly deserts the Night's Watch upon learning of his father's execution, intending to join his brother Robb Stark's army. He is convinced to turn back by Samwell Tarly. **Jeor Mormont pardons the indiscretion**, remarking that if he executed every man who contemplated deserting, they would have no men left.

Comment: not abandoning the post but the "mission"... end result seems to be the same as Janos is executed for refusing to man one of the other castles.

Comment: There's night and day, however, between "I'm telling you to do this as we're in the same room", "No" and "Go do that thing", "OK"...many months pass and new evidence comes to light...

Comment: When you have to ask what the punishment is in GoT, this is usually the answer.

Comment: @Skooba: One can argue that Sam's actions are there to _complete_ his mission. He was sent to the Citadel to learn how to fight the Walkers. If Sam feels that his training is holding him back, and returning with the books gives them the best _real_ chance of fighting the walkers, he is not refusing his mission. He merely adapted his approach based on the situation in the Citadel, which is well within the accepted range of how a mission can be completed. It's about the **intention**.

Comment: Similarly, a scout sent beyond the wall, who then returns empty handed because he needed to avoid an unexpected situation, is not guilty of desertion. First of all, he is still loyal to the Night's Watch, and secondly, he is not expected to die trying if the task ends up being impossible regardless of his attempts. **Janos** was guilty of willful insubordination. Sam is not. He is still completing the same mission (learning how to fight the walkers). Becoming a maester was the way he was suggested to approach this mission, it was not the end goal by itself.